# iOS UI testing tap first cell of table and failed to quiesce within 60s

Tags: ios, user-interface

Hi I'm a complete newbie teaching myself to UI test. I'm working on an iOS note app and trying to test the deletion of draft notes by creating a draft note and then deleting it right away. There's a list of options you can choose when creating a note, but I just want to default select the first one and am struggling to do so. What I have so far is:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let tablesQuery = app.tables
_ = self.expectationForPredicate(
    NSPredicate(format: "self.count = 1"),
    evaluatedWithObject: tablesQuery,
    handler: nil)

let cells = tablesQuery.cells
let firstCell = cells.elementBoundByIndex(0)
firstCell.tap() // my attempt
```

On that last line of code, I get this error:

```
UI Testing Failure - App failed to quiesce within 60s
```

And I couldn't find anything online to help me with this error.
I don't really know much about the syntax and was looking for some guidance. Thank you.